# Regular expression to find a character of a string

Tags: mysql, regex

I have some table names like below

```
123_atest
123_ctest
999_ktest
k12_ktest
z32_ztest_1
```

Now from this list I want to select table that start with `0-9 and a-d`. I have done like below

```
TABLE_NAME REGEXP '^[0-9a-d]'
```

I got the result like below

```
123_atest
123_ctest
999_ktest
```

No I want to get the table names that start with `k-z` after the first underscore

Expected result

```
999_ktest
k12_ktest
z32_ztest_1
```

How do I construct the `regexp`

Comment: Use `^[^_]*_[k-z]`

Comment: @ctwheels maybe you should post your comment as an answer

Comment: I'm trying, but eating an apple and typing is challenging

Comment: Just a small note - the regex in MySQL is case insensitive by default. `[k-z]` will also match `K`. You need to use a BINARY keyword in case it is important.

Comment: To clarify at the start is all letters or yes a to d and k, z and numbers 0 to 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use this /^[0-9a-dkz]*_[k-z]/

- ^ Matches beginning of input
- [0-9a-dkz] Match all number between 0-9  a-d all letter between a to d and match k only.
- * Matches the preceding expression 0 or more times
- [k-z] Match all letter between k to z

for this result

> /^[0-9a-dkz]*_[k-z]/

- 999_ktest
- k12_ktest
- z32_ztest_1

Comment: Forgot the z I edit the answer thanks @ctwheels for the showing up that mistake

Answer (score 1):

#### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/KSxAud/1)

```
^[^_]*_[k-z]
```

To only match alphanumeric characters at the start you can use any of the following:

```
^[^\W_]*_[k-z]
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*_[k-z]
^[[:alnum:]]*_[k-z]
```

#### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[^_]*` Match any character except `_` any number of times
- `_` Match this literally
- `[k-z]` Match any character in the range `k-z`

Comment: This answer is good but it will match fot all letter at the started @nmr can give us a clarify if he wants to be all letters or yes a to d and k, z

Comment: @Angel updated with a few patterns that will only match alphanumeric characters at the start

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex !
You need to extract everything but not underscore '_' multiple times and then the range of k-z is mention in character class ,after that 'test' must be matched .

```
^[^_]*_[k-z]test(.)*
```

[image: output]